# PYTHON scrapy selenium WebDriverWait

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, webdriverwait

Experts here, I am searching for your help if you don't mind it.

Recently, I am working out a web crawler using scrapy and selenium in python. My mind has crush.

I just want to ask whether it is possible that you still get empty even if you've used the statement

`WebDriverWait(driver, 100, 0.1).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,xxxxx)))`

to get those elements. And also, it **even doesn't take 100 second** to get empty. Why?

And by the way, it is a random thing, which means this phenomenon happens anywhere, anytime.

Does getting empty had something about my network connection?

Could you help me or give me some opinions, suggestion about the question above?

Thanks a lot!

-----------------------supplementary notes-----------------------

Thanks for the heads up.

In summary, I used `scrapy` and `selenium` to crawl a site about reviews and write the username, posting time, comment content, etc. to a `.xlsx file` via `pipeline.py`, I wanted it to be as fast as possible while gathering complete information.

A page with many people commenting, and because the review text is too long it gets put away, which means that almost 20 comments per page have their expand button.

Therefore, I need to use `selenium` to `click the expand button` and then use driver to fetch the complete comment. Common sense dictates that it takes **a bit of time** to load after the expand button is clicked, and I believe the time it takes depends on the speed of the network. So using `WebDriverWait` seems to be a wise choice here. After my practice, the default parameters `timeout=10` and `poll_frequency=0.5` seem to be too slow and error-prone. So I considered using the specifications of `timeout=100` and `poll_frequency=0.1`.

However, the problem is that every time I run the project through the `cmd` statement `scrapy crawl spider`, there are always several comment crawls that are empty, and each time the location of the empty is different. I've thought about using `time.sleep()` to force a stop, but that would take a lot of time if every page did that, and while it's certainly a more useful way to get complete information. Also, it's looks not so elegant and a little bit clumsy in my opinion.

Have I express my question clearly?

-------------------------------add something--------------------------------

The exact meaning of  `I got somwhere empty` is shown as the picture below.

[image]

---------------------------add my code--------------------------2022/5/18

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://movie.douban.com/subject/5045678/reviews?start=0')

users = [el.text for el in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[class=name]')]
dates = [el.text for el in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class=main-meta]')]
full_content, words = [], []
unfolds = WebDriverWait(driver,100,0.1).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='unfold']")))

# Here's how I think about and design my loop body.
# I click the expansion bottun, then grab the text, then put it away, then move on to the next one.
for i in range(len(unfolds)):
    unfolds[i].click()
    time.sleep(1)
    # After the javascript, the `div[@class='review-content clearfix']` appear,
    # and some of the full review content will be put in a `<p></p>` label
    find_full_content_p = WebDriverWait(driver,100,0.1).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='review-content clearfix']/p")))
    full_content_p = [j.text for j in find_full_content_p]
    # and some of them will just put in `div[@class='review-content clearfix']` itself.
    find_full_content_div = WebDriverWait(driver,100,0.1).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='review-content clearfix']")))
    full_content_div = [j.text for j in find_full_content_div]
    
    # and I made a list merge
    full_content_p.extend(full_content_div)
    full_content.append("".join(full_content_p))
    words.append(len("".join(full_content_p)))
    time.sleep(1)
    
    # then put it away
    WebDriverWait(driver,100,0.1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='fold']"))).click()
driver.close()
pd.DataFrame({"users":users, "dates":dates, "full_content":full_content, "words":words})
```

[image]

AND, **this is the code of an expert I genuinely respect named sound wave.**(This is slightly modified, the core code has not been changed)

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://movie.douban.com/subject/5045678/reviews?start=0')

users = [el.text for el in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[class=name]')]
dates = [el.text for el in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class=main-meta]')]
reviews, words = [], []
for review in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.review-short'):
    show_more = review.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.unfold')
    if show_more:
        # scroll to the show more button, needed to avoid ElementClickInterceptedException
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"});', show_more[0])
        show_more[0].click()
        review = review.find_element(By.XPATH, 'following-sibling::div')
        while review.get_attribute('class') == 'hidden':
            time.sleep(0.2)
        review = review.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.review-content')
    reviews.append(review.text)
    words.append(len(review.text))
    print('done',len(reviews),end='\r')
 pd.DataFrame({"users":users,"dates":dates,"reviews":reviews,"words":words})
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I made some additions as above.

Comment: Could you post a page of the site where there is a comment that has to be expanded?

Comment: Of course, thanks your attention. Just like the IMDb, `https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1683526/reviews/?ref_=tt_ql_urv`
you can see every reviewer has a lot of text, so it put away. After your click at the button like "v", you can also click the button like "^".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEW

Added code for the site `douban`. To export the scraped data to a csv see the pandas code in the OLD section below

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('...'))

driver.get('https://movie.douban.com/subject/5045678/reviews?start=0')

users = [el.text for el in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[class=name]')]
dates = [el.text for el in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class=main-meta]')]
reviews = []
for review in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.review-short'):
    show_more = review.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.unfold')
    if show_more:
        # scroll to the show more button, needed to avoid ElementClickInterceptedException
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"});', show_more[0])
        show_more[0].click()
        review = review.find_element(By.XPATH, 'following-sibling::div')
        while review.get_attribute('class') == 'hidden':
            time.sleep(0.2)
        review = review.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.review-content')
    reviews.append(review.text)
    print('done',len(reviews),end='\r')
```

---

OLD

For the website you mentioned (imdb.com) in order to scrape the hidden content there is no need to click on the show more button because the text is already loaded in the HTML code, simply it is not shown on the site. So you can scrape all the comments in a single time. Code below stores users, dates and reviews in seprate lists, and finally save data to a `.csv` file.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chromedriver_path))

driver.get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1683526/reviews')
# sets a maximum waiting time for .find_element() and similar commands
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

reviews = [el.get_attribute('innerText') for el in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.text')]
users = [el.text for el in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.display-name-link')]
dates = [el.text for el in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.review-date')]

# store data in a csv file
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(users,dates,reviews)), columns=['user','date','review'])
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\your_name\Desktop\data.csv', index=False)
```

To print a single review you can do something like this

```
i = 0
print(f'User: {users[i]}\nDate: {dates[i]}\n{reviews[i]}')
```

the output (truncated) is

```
User: dschmeding
Date: 26 February 2012
Wow! I was not expecting this movie to be this engaging. Its one of those films...
```

Comment: Brilliant! Your answer is inspiring! 

But I am sorry about that I thought IMDb is a proper example to describe my question in a simple and effective way. Because after reading your answer a few minutes ago, I found the structure of IMDb website **is not quite same** as I expected before. Actually, I was stuck in this website:

`https://movie.douban.com/subject/5045678/reviews?start=0`.

Comment: I believe the structure of the website called `douban` is different from the IMDb. Those expansion buttons really hide their text by some javascript code, which means I have to click the button to load the full content. And yet, IMDb doesn’t need to click them to load the full content because they has been rendered while getting the response.

Could you have a trial in the new website above? (I hope the language in it won't bother you sincerely.❤)

Comment: @Glaze-sauce answer updated with the code for douban, enjoy

Comment: You're excellent! I copied your new code to have a try, exactly it works! Thank you very much!
I still got something not quite understanded. For example, does the statement `driver.find_element(BY.XPATH, ...)` differ from the statement `driver.find_element(BY.CSS_SELECTOR, ...)` in response speed, memory load or anything else?

Comment: And also, I will get uncomplete content or an error when my network was not so good, is it possible? If yes, does we should use `time.sleep()` or `driver.implicitly_wait()`, `WebDriverWait(driver, ..., ...)` to avoid the situation? @soundwave

Comment: @Glaze-sauce xpath and css_selector have same speed and memory, if possible i prefer css because it let you write short strings compared to xpath, for example to find a div element with class 'text' the css code is simply `div.text` while xpath is longer `//div[@class, 'text']`)

Comment: @Glaze-sauce I suggest you to use time.sleep only if it is not required great precision. Usually i use driver.implicitly_wait() because with it you don't have to write many WebDriverWait. But in some cases it is better to use WebDriverWait, it depends on what you are doing

Comment: @Glaze-sauce Remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Thanks your suggestion about using CSS_SELECTOR or XPATH. In my code, everywhere I use `driver` to loacte the element, I use `WebDriverWait(driver, 100, 0.1).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(.......))`. But actually, every time I run my program, there are a few, just several places empty. I am sure about the statement `WebDriverWait` really executed, but still got no content. And next time I run my program, the position of the missing changed. Like a mosquito in sleep, it bites you here this second and in another place after a few seconds. @soundwave

Comment: @Glaze-sauce do you get empty also when using my code?

Comment: Thing is, since I copy your code and run it on my computer (*My computer even haven't shut off yet.*), **it runs perfectly and stably, gets full content and never get a miss**. How **amazing and admiring** it is? It’s quite hard to understand why my code or method couldn’t work effective and efficient as yours. Could you take a few minutes to read my code and point out my problem? Appreciate it!
I added my code to my problem. @soundwave

Comment: @Glaze-sauce Yes I will check your code to see where the problem is, meanwhile could you accept the answer?

Comment: You help me a lot, of course I'm willing to.✨❣️

Comment: I am new to this website, even though I believe I have accepted your answer, I still may have some wrong operation causing me to not accept your answer, you could remind me again.@soundwave

Comment: Hello, are you still at it? Could you please talk to me about the problem you have met? @sound wave

Comment: @Glaze-sauce hi, did you try to put `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"});', unfolds[i])` as first line in the for loop?

Comment: No, I didn't. I believe that would not be the key of it on account of that most of the time the page could roll by itself. My preliminary conclusion is it has something about the network connection, because when I click the `unfold` button, it seldom take more than 5 seconds to load the full content. As long as I give it more time, it can be got more completely. But exactly this reason push me to search other methods to let my program  wiser and stabler. @sound wave